# Construct the angle whose sine is $\frac{3}{2+\sqrt{5}}$

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I saw this question in an old trig text book:

> Construct the angle whose sine is $\frac{3}{2+\sqrt{5}}$.

I ask:

1. What solution can people here give ?
2. Is there a solution that does not (like mine) require the construction of $\sqrt[4]{5}$ ? In other words, a solution without assuming the circle intersection property (See Hartshore: Euclid and Beyond pg. 144)

Comment: Please include your construction. It may provide a jumping-off point for other solutions, and it can help people avoid wasting time duplicating your effort. (That said, it seems straightforward enough, starting with a segment of length $a$, to construct $2a$ and $a\sqrt{5}$, and then $2a+a\sqrt{5}$, and also $3a$, without fourth-roots.)

Comment: It's slightly easier once you rationalize the denominator.

Comment: @Blue It is not enough to just construct the lengths $2+\sqrt{5}$ and  $3$, you must put them in a triangle with hypotenuse $2+\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Once you have the lengths, putting them on the hypotenuse and one leg of a right triangle is simple.

Comment: @DavidK Sorry, I dont see that, what is the construction ?  Not using circle intersection property ?

Comment: On a segment of length $a,$ a circle of radius $c$ with center at one end of the segment intersects a line perpendicular to the other end of the segment. It's the last step of Dr. Mathva's construction, but it's generally good for any leg and hypotenuse lengths with $a < c.$

Answer (score 4):

*Outline.* Let $A=(0,2)$ and $B=(1,0)$. Consider the circle around $A$ with radius $AB=\sqrt{5}$, which intersects the $y$-Axis at $C=(0, 2+\sqrt{5})$. Let now $\Gamma$ be the circle centered at $O=(0,0)$ through $C$ which intersects the line $l$ through $D=(0,3)$ and parallel to the $x$-Axis at $E$. Then

> $$\sin\angle DEO=\frac{OD}{OE}=\frac3{2+\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: Nice construction.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$|OB'|= \sqrt{5} \quad\to\quad |C'D|=3(\sqrt{5}-2) \quad\to\quad \sin A'' = \frac{3(\sqrt{5}-2)}{1}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}+2}$$